# How to reverse engineer this equation

Tags: algorithm, cocos2d-x

I got an algorithm from a game engine on how to compute pixel position from tile position on a staggered tile map.

This algorithm gets the tile position using pixel position:

```
float diffX = 0;
if ((int)tilePos.y % 2 == 1)
    diffX = tileSize.width / 2;
return Vec2 (
    tilePos.x * tileSize.width + diffX,
    (mapSize.height - tilePos.y - 1) * tileSize.height / 2);
```

How to reverse this algorithm to get tile position using pixel position.

[image]

Comment: @appleapple, SO is a place to ask help if you cant solve it. It not asking people to write code for you. My attempts do not get the correct answer. Thus, i'm here asking for help.

Comment: @theMayer, this is my attempt:
 float tileX = (pixelPos.y / tileSize.height) + (pixelPos.x / tileSize.width);
 float tileY = (pixelPos.x / tileSize.width) - (pixelPos.y / tileSize.height);
i'm wondering how to tackle the staggered formation part.

Comment: @theMayer Please don't write sendtehcodez comments for questions that don't need it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291399/is-there-really-a-universal-code-requirement

Answer (score 0):

Divide the plane into the rectangles circumscribing the tiles with even y coordinate, then adjust the result if it's in one of the four corner triangles that belong to another tile. Something like

```
# px is pixel x, py is pixel y
x = round(px / width)
y = 2 * round(py / height)
dx = px / width - x
dy = py / height - y / 2
if dx + dy > 0.5:
    y = y + 1
elif dx - dy > 0.5:
    y = y - 1
elif -dx + dy > 0.5:
    x = x - 1
    y = y + 1
elif -dx - dy > 0.5:
    x = x - 1
    y = y - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, this grid is split into rectangles like [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K1yf.png). In this solution, it is assumed that x increases rightwards and y increases downwards. The origin, {0,0} in terms of pixels, is where the light blue circle is as [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keIKj.png). Coordinates of these rectangles will look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6KSe.png).

```
int px = pixel.x;
int py = pixel.y;
int w = tileSize.width;
int h = tileSize.height;

// find the coord that the pixel is in, in terms of the small rectangles
int x = 2px / w;
int y = 2py / h;
```

At this point, determine whether the pixel falls in which of the small rectangle as [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfOXa.png). For this scenario, pixel is in

- A : if [x_,y_] == [0,0]
- B : if [x_,y_] == [1,0]
- C : if [x_,y_] == [0,1]
- D : if [x_,y_] == [1,1]

Knowing which rectangle the pixel is in will help us further modify [x,y] to find the actual coordinate in this staggered tile map. Here, tangent is used to determine if x or y needs to be increased, together with the knowledge of whether the pixel is in A, B, C or D. A is grouped with D while B is grouped with C due to identical tangent value.

```
// relative x and y value in small rectangle
int px_ = px % w;
int py_ = py % h;
// calculate tangent of tile
float tan_tile = h / w;
bool isInfinite = ( 0 == px );
float tan_pixel = 0.0f;
if ( !isInfinite  )
{
    tan_pixel = py_ / px_;
}

// pixel is in A or D
if ( 0 == ( x + y ) % 2 )
{
    // tangent value is infinite
    if ( 0 == px )
    {
        y += 1;

    else
    {
        // For A and D, tangents are flipped along y-axis
        if ( -tan_pixel <= -tan_tile )
        {
            y += 1;
        }
    }
}
// pixel is in B or C
else
{
    // tangent value is infinite
    if ( 0 == px )
    {
        y += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( tan_pixel > tan_tile )
        {
            y += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The above portion can be simplified further as

```
-tan_pixel <= -tan_tile
```

is actually

```
tan_pixel > tan_tile
```

Therefore, the part where tangent is compared becomes

```
// relative x and y value in small rectangle
int px_ = px % w;
int py_ = py % h;
// calculate tangent of tile
float tan_tile = h / w;
if ( 0 == px )
{
    y += 1;
}
else
{
    float tan_pixel = py_ / px_;
    if ( tan_pixel > tan_tile )
    {
        y += 1;
    }
}
```

Origin is in the center of tile [0,0], so x needs to be incremented by 1. This tile map is staggered such that x increases by 1 with width of 2 rectangles while y increases by 1 height of 1 rectangle, we need to divide x by 2 to get the actual coordinate.

```
x = ( x + 1 ) / 2;
```

And there you have it, the tile coordinate of pixel in this staggered map.